# Sites do not redirect to the question after log in

Tags: bug, login, redirection

When user switches between "[Log in](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login)" and "[Sign up](https://stackoverflow.com/users/signup)", the `returnurl` parameter get lost.

Here is how to reproduce it:

1. Open a private tab or log out.
2. Go to [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514705/installing-pycharm-in-ubuntu-12-10).
3. Try to upvote something. At "Thanks for feedback!" pop-up, click on one of "Sign up using ..." buttons.
4. Realise that you clicked on "Sign up" button instead of "Log in", so [switch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login) tabs.
5. Log in but, oops, where is the question?